# <VirtualHost fqdn.mydomain.com:80> not recommended?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

In [Apache2 documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#virtualhost/) thay say that in `<VirtualHost *:80>`, the `*` can be replaced by IP *or FQDN*, but the FQDN is not recommended.

> Addr can be:
>
> - The IP address of the virtual host;
> - A fully qualified domain name for the IP address of the virtual host (not recommended);

But **why** is it not recommended?  If I have www.mydomain.com and webmail.mydomain.com pointing to the same IP address, why shouldn't I use the names here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By using a name there, you're introducing another dependency: a functioning DNS resolver.

Comment: i do not understand this answer. if domain is not written here, it should be written after ServerName, what is difference? why dns resolver is needed? job of apache is just get and serve a ready request with ip and domain name provided, apache does not need to resolve domain name here.